# iterating over long list to generate smaller lists and append to csv

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, csv

Struggling with doing this and was wondering if someone can help.
I have a code that generates a large list of 300 items.
I want to write this to a csv file using pandas but write different sub lists to different rows.
for example
Take items 0-7 and write to one row, then 1-8, 2-9 and so on until 293-300.
currently what i have being doing is this and manually changing the selection in
 `df.iloc[:,2:9]`
but i was hoping there would be a way to automate this with a loop.

This is what i have as an example so far.
sncomo is just a package to generate data. its output is what I want to split up and save to a csv file.

```
import sncosmo
import pandas as pd

days_apart = list(range(55, 300))
model = sncosmo.Model(source="hsiao")
model.set(z=1.5, t0=100)
y = model.bandmag('desr', 'ab', days_apart)
df = pd.DataFrame([y])
df1 = df.iloc[:,2:9]
with open("test_data.csv", "a") as f:
    df1.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

Hope someone can help thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a `for` loop with `enumerate`

```
import sncosmo
import pandas as pd

days_apart = list(range(55, 300))
model = sncosmo.Model(source="hsiao")
model.set(z=1.5, t0=100)
y = model.bandmag('desr', 'ab', days_apart)
df = pd.DataFrame([y])
for i, j in enumerate(range(6,300)):
    df1 = df.iloc[:,i:j+1]
    with open("test_data.csv", "a") as f:
        df1.to_csv(f, header=False)
```